# Jupyter Notebook Counter when processing

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using Jupyter Notebook and Python 3.0.

I have a block of code that takes a while to execute in Jupyter Notebook and to identify its current status, I would like to make a counter of what loop it is on, something like this:

```
large_number = 1000
for i in range(large_number):
    print('{} / {} complete.'.format(i,large_number))
```

The problem with this is that it will print a new line for each iteration, which I do not want to do... instead I just want to update the value.

Is there anyway I can do this in Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fond of making an ascii status bar. Say you need to run 1000 iterations and want to see 20 updates before it is done:

```
num_iter = 1000
num_updates = 20
update_per = num_iter // num_updates  # make sure it's an integer
print('|{}|'.format(' ' * (num_updates - 2)))  # gives you a reference
for i in range(num_iter):
    # code stuff
    if i % update_per == 0:
        print('*', end='', flush=True)
```

Gives you an update that looks like:

```
|                  |
*******
```

as it runs.

Comment: just a note on this answer (which I love by the way!)
you need to put brackets around the 'num_updates - 2'
    print('|{}|'.format(' ' * (num_of_updates - 2)))

Comment: Right you are! I fixed it.

Comment: I had to rush out the office due to fire alarm... I forgot to come back and accept. apologies :(

Answer (score 6):

The de facto standard for this functionality in Jupyter is [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm), specifically tqdm_notebook. It is simple to use, provides informative output, and has a multitude of options. You can also use it for cli work.

```
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook
from time import sleep

for i in tqdm_notebook(range(100)):
    sleep(.05)
```

The output would be something like this:

[image]

Comment: Good one! This works OOTB in my anaconda, without having to install any package!

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys

large_number = 1000
for i in range(large_number):
    print('{} / {} complete.'.format(i,large_number), end='\r')
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: I do not know what is happening when I run this...
it seems to lag out my system but maybe that is because its refreshing so far with such a simple loop to test it out with?

Answer (score 0):

I always find that [Alexander Kukushkin's Jupyter Widget](https://github.com/alexanderkuk/log-progress) is the best for these sorts of things. It creates a nice looking progress bar, can work on generators and you can set how often it updates the progress value.

To use it, copy the code from the github link into a cell, then run your code like so:

```
large_number = 1000
for i in log_progress(range(large_number)):
    //your code here - no need to print anything manually!
```

Comment: That's awesome.